# XSL move a child depending on ID to new parent element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Is there a way to move a children, depending on ID, two levels back, into a new element, untouching all other content?
Move the node `<com>` with `id="something"` into the new node `<ele id="999">`. If the condition is not matched, do nothing.
Initial XML:

```
<lev0>
 <lev1>
   <ele id="2">
    <lev3>
     <lev4 id="a_dif_thing">
       <com id="">text 1</com>
       <com id="">text 2</com>
     </lev4>
    </lev3>
   </ele>
   <ele id="1">
    <lev3>
     <lev4 id="a_thing">
       <com id="otherthing">text</com>
       <com id="otherthing">text <i>italic</i></com>
       <com id="something"><span>text text</span></com>
     </lev4>
    </lev3>
   </ele>
   <ele>
    <lev3>
     <lev4>
       <com id="">text</com>
     </lev4>
    </lev3>
   </ele>
 </lev1>
</lev0>
```

Output XML:

```
<lev0>
 <lev1>
   <ele id="2">
    <lev3>
     <lev4 id="a_dif_thing">
       <com id="">text 1</com>
       <com id="">text 2</com>
     </lev4>
    </lev3>
   </ele>
   <ele id="1">
    <lev3>
     <lev4 id="a_thing">
       <com id="otherthing">text</com>
       <com id="otherthing">text <i>italic</i></com>
     </lev4>
    </lev3>
   </ele>
   <ele id="999">
    <lev3>
     <lev4 id="a_new_thing">
       <com id="something"><span>text text</span></com>
     </lev4>
    </lev3>
   </ele>
   <ele>
    <lev3>
     <lev4>
       <com id="">text</com>
     </lev4>
    </lev3>
   </ele>
 </lev1>
</lev0>
```

Example edited to show the preferable place of each new `<ele>` created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***--- edited in response to your clarifications ---***

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ele[descendant::com[@id='something']]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <!-- append a new branch to folow this node-->
        <ele id="999">
            <lev3>
                <lev4 id="a_new_thing">
                    <!-- copy matching nodes -->
                    <xsl:copy-of select="descendant::com[@id='something']"/>
                </lev4>
            </lev3>
        </ele>
</xsl:template>

<!-- suppress moved nodes -->
<xsl:template match="com[@id='something']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you to for this quick solution. I've added the line `<xsl:if test="key('com-by-id', 'id')">` before adding the new branch, and it works well with 0 to N matches. But, as _Lingamurthy CS_ version, it puts all new elements at the end. Any idea of how to put each one after the original node?

Comment: @yfreeman What would be "the original node" in this context? Perhaps you should edit your question and provide an example that has more than one match.

Comment: I've updated the example showing better the preferable place of the new nodes created.

Comment: It works like a charm. 
Thank you both for your help, and time.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this stylesheet helps:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Identity transform template to copy all nodes and attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- template to process 4th ancestor of com[@id = 'something'] -->
    <xsl:template match="*[*/*/*/com[@id = 'something']]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*/*/com[@id = 'something']" mode="special"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- create the element when com[@id = 'something'] is encountered -->
    <xsl:template match="com" mode="special">
        <ele id="999">
            <lev3>
                <lev4 id="a_new_thing">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </lev4>
            </lev3>
        </ele>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- do nothing for com[@id = 'something'] elements -->

    <xsl:template match="*/*/*/*/com[@id = 'something']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! It works well with 0 to N matches. It's just that it puts the moved nodes to the end of the XML file.
Is there a way to create the new node after the one that contains the match?

Comment: @yfreeman do you mean you don't want the new node to be moved some levels up and just created in the same position as in input?

Comment: No, no. Just as you do in your solution, but after the modified `<ele>`; not at the end of the file.
I've updated the example showing better the preferable place of the new nodes created.